# Accessing data from my SqlDataSource in the code behind C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a contact page where there is a datalist of people and if you click on one of them you get a contact form that I want to send to that particular person.

I use sqldatasource dscontactemail to get information about that person to place on the contact form but how do I get information out of dscontactemail from the code behind for when I'm ready to send that mail?

I put a formview on the page to display the person's picture and I can get whatever I want from that dscontactemail with <%#Eval("email") for example, but how do I get that from the code behind?

I tried a hidden field but it didn't work.

Any other ways to access the SqlDataSource on a page from the code behind?

Comment: By datasource do you mean, like  repeater/data grid?

Comment: @Spencer is completely right.  Get out of the habit of using SQLDataSource etc... do not use the toolbox! for anything but UI items :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should graduate from using SqlDataSource to the classes available in the SqlClient namespace at some point so keep that in mind.

Here's the code to do it though:

```
DataView dview = CType(yourSqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView);
string str = "";

foreach(DataRow drow dview.Table.Rows)
{
    str += drow("yourcol1").ToString() + "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I agree on the graduating part.  Not a fan of using DataView though.

Comment: But there is one problem, CType is in VB not C#

Answer (score 0):

The following is more than sufficient:

```
dv = yourSqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;
```

And interrogate the DataView separately.

If intellisense does not pickup yourSqlDataSource, then simply bind it via the FindControl() of the control that has the data source:

```
        SqlDataSource sdsPreStartDates = (SqlDataSource)DetailsView1.FindControl("sdsPreStartDates");
        if (sdsPreStartDates != null)
        {
            DataView dv1 = (DataView)sdsPreStartDates.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
..
.. etc
}
```